# Write a SQL query to find those values from column A in table X that are NOT present in column B of table Y

Tags: sql, oracle

Write a SQL query to find those values from column A in table X that are NOT present in column B of table Y.

update: the query is taking too long with not in(more than 5 minutes, i didn't wait for it to complete)  The column B in table Y is a primary key.

update: im using oracle. The table size is in millions(rows) for both tables. Of course, I'm using another WHERE clause, which means I'm comparing about 500,000 rows of table X with millions of rows in table Y

Comment: I wouldn't close it as "not a real question". Duplicate of another question, perhaps, but it's a valid question...

Comment: Hi Shishir,

Which version of SQL (Oracle, SQLServer, MYSQL, etc.) are you using, and roughly how many rows are in table B? Different versions of SQL may have optimum performance from different ways of performing the same query; this may also be dependant on table size. (Table scans versus index scans.)

Comment: Is there an index on column A in table X?

Comment: yes, the column is a part two indexes that have two other columns in them too.

Comment: @shishir - This article reckons that using `MINUS` will give you better performance http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_subq_rewrite.htm

Comment: @martin. that's right. MINUS worked well!! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 ways to do this that I can think of.

- Not In (careful of NULLs)
- OUTER JOIN
  and filter on NULL (may need DISTINCT added)
- NOT EXISTS
- EXCEPT (Following update in question Oracle uses the non standard `MINUS` operator for this)

This last one appears to be [the preferred way of doing it](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_subq_rewrite.htm) in Oracle though I can't vouch for that myself.

Comment: Worth nothing you may need DISTINCT with the OUTER JOIN...?

Comment: Note: EXCEPT only exists in SQL Server 2005 upwards.

Comment: @Ardman  EXCEPT is standard SQL though. The OP hasn't specified any particular flavour. Quick Google says it is supported in sybase http://dcx.sybase.com/1100en/dbusage_en11/set-operations-sorting.html and postgres sql http://www.postgresql.org/files/documentation/books/aw_pgsql/node80.html

Answer (score 7):

You ***can't*** rely on `NOT IN` if you ***any*** NULLS in Y.B

```
Select A from X where not EXISTS (select * from Y where Y.B = X.A)
```

The safest way in general is `NOT EXISTS`. An `OUTER JOIN` may give more more rows if, say, Y is a child of A

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Select A from X where not A in (select B from Y)
```